# Can artificial satellite positions affect tides?

Tags: tides

The Moon's position affects tides. So, is there any possibility for man-made satellite positions to also affect tides?

Comment: Related: [Do flights affect tides?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/17182/3244)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Note: this is a '[Fermi estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem)' answer, so I'm going to round off and ignore minor effects.

Tides are caused by gravity, and gravity is a really weak force. The [mass](https://www.universetoday.com/19728/mass-of-the-moon/) of the Moon is 7 x 10<sup>22</sup> kg, and it causes tides where the difference between water levels is on the order of 10 m.

Satellites are on the order of 10<sup>3</sup> kg, and they're 10<sup>3</sup> times closer, so the tidal effect caused by the average satellite is 10<sup>13</sup> times smaller, and that's too small to be measurable.

Another factor is the number of satellites: 1000 sats in orbits evenly distributed around Earth will cancel out each other's tidal effects.

Comment: Another small correction: the amplitude of tides is proportional not to the strength of the gravity force, which is proportional to $r^{-2}$, but to its gradient, which is proportional to $r^{-3}$. So a satellite's tides would be "only" about $10^{10}$ times smaller than the Moon's.

Comment: Good answer, but tides are actually only about 0.5m. Everything bigger than that is caused by the water sloshing around in the ocean bed – or, if you want to put it more respectably, by the rhythm of the tidal pull exciting a resonance in the given body of water.

Comment: It might help to be clearer that a fact of $10^3$ in distance means a factor of $10^9$ in tidal effect.

Comment: Technically, a satellite will affect tides, just like every other object with mass in the universe. However, the impact would be so incredibly small that it would be immeasurable

Comment: I just did the numbers quickly, but I think Pluto has a substantially larger effect on the tides than a satelite does.

Comment: While all the regular satellites might be pretty evenly distributed, how about the ISS? It's around 4e5 kg.

Comment: Airplanes are both much heavier than satellites (excepting ISS) and a lot closer. So  Boeing/Airbus tides should be 100 - 1000 times higher than even the ISS ones.

Comment: @IMil I just posted a question - with some math - on that particular point [here](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/17182/3244).

Comment: To put some numbers on "10^13 times smaller", for perspective - this would create a tide that would raise or lower the level of the water on the order of a fraction (~1%) of an atom in height. (a few picometers).  Even a tide a million times stronger than this would lift the water a tenth of the thickness of a human hair.  It's much, much too small to measure.

Comment: @IMil I can see some pretty harmless your mom jokes here.

Comment: @IMil Boeing and Airbus might not be the best examples, as both companies make satellites too!

Comment: "Another factor is the number of satellites: 1000 sats in orbits evenly distributed around Earth will cancel out each other's tidal effects." Depends on how they're distributed. If they're randomly distributed, 1000 sats would have 30 times the effect of 1, assuming a naive application of the CLT.

Answer (score 7):

Everything that Hobbes says in his answer is correct, but doesn't seem to me to give a clear answer, which is YES they do affect tides, though not to a measurable extent.

When they were launched, that had a tiny effect on the earths rotation, though not particularly relevant here.

Every single one has exactly the same effect as the moon does, but to a far smaller extent, due to the tiny mass. The totality of artificial satellites, including the ISS, are NOT uniformly distributed, so they do not entirely cancel each other out.

Comment: It's like asking "Can a pea raise a truck?" That answer is yes, but the net effect is so small as to be considered 0.

Answer (score 4):

Let's do one small calculation.

The mass of the Moon **~ 7x10^22 kg**, roughly **4x10^8 m** away.

Mass of a really large satellite (ISS) ~ **5x10^6 kg** roughly **4x10^5 m** away.

The magnitude of the tide will be proportional to the mass of the orbiting object, and to first order, proportional to the cube of the distance.

For the Moon, **M/(r^3)** is roughly **0.001**

For the ISS, **M/(r^3)** is roughly **8x10^-11**

So, the ISS raises a tide that is around ***Seven orders (~1x10^7)*** of magnitude weaker than that of the Moon.

Comment: Proportional to the _cube_ of the distance, as others have pointed out.

Comment: No, in this case, it is proportional to the inverse square of the distance.

Comment: Stating it twice [doesn't make it true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force#Size_and_distance).

Comment: Ya, now I understood, will correct it. Thanks!

Comment: Surely the magnitiude will be _inversely_ proportional to distance??